# Wordpress custom gallery metadata url path

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**# DOUBT: this one..... man..... (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻**

I need to create a custom php function to get info from a metadata.
I'm running Wordpress + Real Estate Theme, but the theme gallery do not attach images/pictures in default wordpress gallery. So it creates a meta data that reffer to a link in other metakey via post_id, as you can see here:
[image]

So when I select REAL_HOMES_property_image field to show me picture url, it just shows me: 10462 in xml tag:

```
<REAL_HOMES_property_images><![CDATA[10462]]></REAL_HOMES_property_images>
```

and this should actually looks like this:

```
<REAL_HOMES_property_images><![CDATA[http://localhost:8090/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IMG_3201.jpg]]></REAL_HOMES_property_images>
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks ( ͡ᵔ ͜ʖ ͡ᵔ )

----- Edit
For WP ALL IMPORT plugin I found a way how people solve this problem, although I don't use WP ALL IMPORT (I use WP ALL EXPORT to generete XML):

```
add_action ('pmxi_gallery_image', 'my_gallery_image', 10, 3);
function my_gallery_image ($pid, $AttId, $image_filepath) {
add_post_meta ($pid, "REAL_HOMES_property_images" $AttId, false);
}
```

But this didn't solve my problem and it do not alter a custom value only.

In WP All Export documentation they give us some instructions:

> Example 2 – using a user defined function
>
> Inside WP All Import:

```
[my_custom_function({my_element[1]})]
```

> Inside your theme’s functions.php file:

```
function my_custom_function($x) {
     // do something to $x
     return $x; 
}
```

And as soon as it uses custom gallery, they give us instructions to catch more info:

> pmxi_gallery_image
>
> Description This hook is called after WP All Import creates/updates a
>   post attachment image(s).
>
> Parameters

```
$pid – the ID of the post/page/Custom Post Type that was just created.
$attid – the ID of the attachment
$image_filepath – the full path to the file: C:\path\to\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\2010\05\filename.png
```

> Examples
>
> a.

```
<?php 
add_action('pmxi_gallery_image', 'my_gallery_image', 10, 3);function my_gallery_image($pid, $attid, $image_filepath){
$attachment = get_post($attid);
// do something with $attachment image
}

?>
```

Comment: What about some code?

Comment: @Berriel there it go. See my edited post :D